# android edittext in dialog returns null

Tags: android, android-edittext

Right now im feeling really dumb and I really hope ill be able to find a solution like that.

What I want to do: the Alert has an edittext, the input from this edittext will be used in the next activity
my problem is that the string test is always null. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void CalibrateButtonClicked(View v) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
builder.setMessage("calibration");


builder.setView(dialogView)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              //  startActivity(new Intent(FaceMenu.this, FaceTrackerActivity.class));
               EditText edit = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String test= edit.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FaceTrackerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", test);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        })
        .create().show();
}
```

Comment: The `EditText` is null, or `getText().toString()` returns an empty `String`?

Comment: test is null, what means that getText().toString() is null too

Comment: `getText().toString()` won't return null. It might return an empty `String`, but that's not the same thing. Is it returning an empty `String`, or is something crashing there?

Comment: Ok im dumb ... I called the wrong class ... bah thats dumb... but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `EditText` outside to your `setPositiveButton`

like:

```
public void CalibrateButtonClicked(View v) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
final EditText edit = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

builder.setMessage("calibration");
builder.setView(dialogView)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              //  startActivity(new Intent(FaceMenu.this, FaceTrackerActivity.class));
                String test= edit.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FaceTrackerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", test);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        })
        .create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put view binding out of `OnClickListener`?

```
public void CalibrateButtonClicked(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final View dialogView = View.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    EditText edit = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    builder.setMessage("calibration");
    builder.setView(dialogView)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //  startActivity(new Intent(FaceMenu.this, FaceTrackerActivity.class));
            String test= edit.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FaceTrackerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", test);
            startActivity(intent);

          }
        })
        .create().show();
  }
```